# In C#, How can I iterate through a entire 2D Array and count the number of 0s?

Tags: c#, arrays

I've been trying to iterate through an entire 2D array and count the number of 0s. How can I do this?

I'm sure I have to use the following to make the program work:

- Use an outer for loop to iterate through the rows of the array
- Use an inner for loop to iterate through the columns of the array
- if `matrix[row,col] == 0`, increment a variable
- To get the number of rows of the 2D array, use the method    `matrix.GetLength(0)`, and to get the number of columns of the array, use the method `matrix.GetLength(1)`

Here's what I have attempted so far:

```
public int Test9(int[,] matrix)
{
    int b = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); i++)
        {
             b = matrix[i, j];
        }
}
```

Comment: You are incrementing `i` in both the for loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can do it..

```
 public int Test9(int[,] matrix)
    {
       int zeroCounter = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
                if(matrix[i, j] == 0)
                {
                    zeroCounter++;
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The test is coming as invalid/fail for all outputs